# How to get output from the console.app from a non-admin account?

Tags: macos, user-account, logs, console, sudo

I almost exclusively use a non-admin account for everyday use. Only for installing software, etc. I log in with the admin account.
This normally works very well, however, there is one issue I haven't been able to resolve so far. The `Console.app` will only show the few log files it has access to. That means, for instance, `/var/log/system.log` will not be displayed.

I know I could log in with the admin account (either in terminal or the desktop environment), but I am looking for a more convenient way to open logs from the non-admin account.